# Have you installed pyodbc on Mac OS X Sierra (10.12)?

Tags: python, macos

I tried installing pyodbc on mac os X sierra. I installed both python 2 and 3 via brew, and use virtualenv to isolate required pacakges etc.
First I tried installing with pip, which failed, then by following: https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/wiki/Mac-setup-to-connect-to-a-MS-SQL-Server, which seemed to be going well, except for the actual pyodbc installation.

Though I have XCode and the tools, all working with brew, I've had issues with libraries that seem to be expected as part of Apple's toolchain. Specifically, I'm getting this missing `sql.h` message:

```
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.10 -DPYODBC_UNICODE_WIDTH=2 -UMAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c /Users/daniellamblin/pyodbc-3.0.10/src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/Users/daniellamblin/pyodbc-3.0.10/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings -Wno-deprecated-declarations
In file included from /Users/daniellamblin/pyodbc-3.0.10/src/buffer.cpp:12:
/Users/daniellamblin/pyodbc-3.0.10/src/pyodbc.h:52:10: fatal error: 'sql.h' file
      not found
#include <sql.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

What's odd about all this is that after using `brew install unixodbc` I found that I have `sql.h` in `/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/include/` and that the files in there are symlinked into `/usr/local/include/` it just doesn't seem to be getting picked up by the setup script somehow.

Has anyone found the right way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to Sierra and updating Xcode (and running it to accept the license) the tools aren't actually fully ready to use.
I had to just rerun `xcode-select --install` which downloaded more and then it was able to include the headers that were indeed already there due to brew's unixodbc.